# Crawler hangs a few urls from the end

Tags: import.io

Whether I paste 2000 urls, 1000, 500 or whatever the crawler works perfectly returning data from the bulk urls BUT then stops a handful of urls from the end and hangs.... as there is no cancel/stop button I have to quit the program.

Example, 250 urls pasted - stops at 247, 2000 urls pasted - stops at 1986

Comment: Hi Rod, are all the URLs you are passing through successful or are some failing? You can tell this by the panel on the top of the crawler.

Answer (score 0):

Rod,

This is usually due to timeouts happening during processing.
Did you try copy pasting the URLs in the Bulk Extract feature instead?
We recently released error handling for Bulk Extract, the process will time out after 1' and you will be able to retry the ones who failed.

See here for an example:
http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/510065-bulk-extract-tutorial